# Send an email after some time (24hours) in django using django_rq

Tags: django, django-rq

I have a website where user profile has multiple steps of registry.
I would like to send the user an email if the user has completed step 1 but not step 2, 24 hours later than completing step 1.
So, after the completion of step 1 I would like to set a task which runs after 24 hours and checks if `User.profile_status == completed_step_2`, and if this is not the case, send him/her an email asking to complete step 2 of their profile.
How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use and configure sendblue api to send emails (its not free), and to shedule that you can use celery .

Useful link :

[Django - How to run a function EVERYDAY?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563934/django-how-to-run-a-function-everyday)