# How to get many to many data in django at same model

Tags: django

```
class Consumer (models.Model):
     name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
     address=models.CharField(max_length=32)
     telephone=models.CharField(max_length=32)
     email=models.CharField(max_length=32)
     ac_no=models.IntegerField(default=0)
class Consumer_order(models.Model):
     name=models.ForeignKey(Consumer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     ac_no=models.ManyToManyField(Consumer)
     newspaper=models.ForeignKey(Newspaper, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     added_date=models.DateField(max_length=32,auto_now_add=True)
```

**i try many ways many to many relationship but not work those error occur (fields.E302,E303,E304).**
**How to get Model Consumer from  ac_no To  Consumer_order to ac_no datafield?**

[ac_no not show integer value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxCQ7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think if i understood well your question, you should add related_name parameter to the field . i think this problem apear because you call the same model twice into your Consumer_order model .

```
    name=models.ForeignKey(Consumer,related_name="Consumer_name", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     
    ac_no=models.ManyToManyField(Consumer,related_name="Consumer_ac_no")
```

Note if you want to acess to ac_no of Consumer model from Consumer_order model you shoud have like this is exemple :

```
 #to get specific object consumer_order in this example I choose object with specific date ,you can crate it ,if you want loop throught all objetcs use objects.all() , you can also directly use .filter : Consumer_order.objects.filter(added_date='2019-11-28').first()
 consumer_order =Consumer_order.objects.get(added_date='2019-11-28')
 #to get all objects consumer into the filed ac_no in Consumer_order model
 ac_no_all =consumer_order.ac_no
 # to loop throught all the consumer object and print ac_no intger
 for ac_no_ in ac_no_all:
     print(ac_no_.ac_no)
```

Comment: it is can add to data. but ac_no data field not show integer value. it is show same name data field  name

Comment: can you show me please how you get the data from ac_no of Consumer_order? and if you can change name  ac_no of Consumer_order to ac_no_order . just to make debuging easy .

Comment: **Here i attach code** https://github.com/Ravindrakumara/Newspaper_tracking

Comment: click above this link i attach screen shot **ac_no not show integer value**

Comment: sorry i didnt see the eror screen just i get link to the project

Comment: in where have to put this Consumer_order.ac_no.ac_no?  i try but did not work

Comment: sorry i didnt explain clearly , i edit my response :) ihope its help you

Comment: Note in your GitHub repo you should add gitgnore file

Comment: is it possible to insert data  Models (A) to Models (B) for every day automatically

Comment: there s 2 part of your question : insert data && evry day automaticly . for the part of insert i think you know now how you do . and for the part of make it automaticly you can use celery https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563934/django-how-to-run-a-function-everyday

Comment: For the part one, i think you mean insert data from Consumer_order to Consumer yes . you can use .add()   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1182380/how-to-add-data-into-manytomany-field

Comment: def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()
           @periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute=30, hour='7', day_of_week='mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat,sun'))
           self.ac_no = self.Consumer_order.ac_no
           self.newspaper = self.Consumer_order.newspaper 
           super(Daily_Cart, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

Comment: i code this every task. it not work. my mind stuck do not know

Comment: Please open new issue !

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the [`related_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name)**

```
class Consumer(models.Model):
     name=models.CharField(max_length=32)
     address=models.CharField(max_length=32)
     telephone=models.CharField(max_length=32)
     email=models.EmailField(max_length=32)
     ac_no=models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=254)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name

class Consumer_order(models.Model):
     name=models.ForeignKey(Consumer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='consumer')
     ac_no=models.ManyToManyField(Consumer)
     newspaper=models.ForeignKey(Newspaper, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='xyz')
     added_date=models.DateField(max_length=32,auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: ac_no means Account number so should have to integer. may i know what is the reason has to change char field?

Comment: @Ravi account number is consider as varchar so i use CharField but if you require integer field  then use models.BigAutoField.

Comment: @Ravi BigAutofield is not working or you not able to add account number in your admin template in your consumer_order ???

Comment: @Ravi If your consumer_order table in acc_no. not showing then [`follow this stack question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field)